# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to create a twitter bot extension, and I started by retweeting post, but I got the problem : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9krB.jpg

After that I have tried to execute this code in the console :

```
var RetweetButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='retweet']")
RetweetButton[0].click()
var     RetweetButtonConfirm = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='retweetConfirm']");
RetweetButtonConfirm[0].click()
```

I typed each command followed by ENTER
and it worked.
But when I typed all code one time followed by Enter it gave me the same error here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9krB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PIPz.jpg

I don't know why my script doesn't work

```
var RetweetButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='retweet']")
var time = new Date();
function Wait(second) 
{
    var iteration = true;   
    while(iteration) {
        if(time.getTime() + second*1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
            iteration = false;
        }
    } 
}
for (let step = 0; step <RetweetButton.length; step++){
    RetweetButton[step].click();
    Wait(20);
    RetweetButtonConfirm = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='retweetConfirm']");
    RetweetButtonConfirm[0].click();
    Wait(30);
}
```

Comment: try `var RetweetButtonConfirm = document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid='retweetConfirm']");`? Also if that doesn't work can you do a `console.log(RetweetButton, RetweetButtonConfirm)`?

Comment: yes i can do it with no error

Comment: Is it possible that it works on the first iteration, but then after the actual retweet, the attribute data-testid changes ? The timing function works fine. So the DOM invisibility should not be the problem. I don't have a twitter unfortunately to check.